# how to not post empty select options from html to php

Tags: php, forms

i have some select options in my form which will post data to my script.but

```
    <select name="city" id="City">
    <option></option>
    </select>
    <select name="country" id="Country">
    <option></option>
    </select>
```

but when they are empty they post data with no value somthing like this:

```
city=&country=&
```

i know i can unset them by unset command.but when i pass these data to javascript library(jquery) and serialize theme everyone can see them in firebug.how can i prevent empty select options to not post data?

thanks

Comment: Why do you have empty selects?

Comment: beacause when i choose country cities will fetch data by ajax.then cities field is empty in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your using jQuery here is a quick mock up of something that you could adapt and utilize, where adding a disabled attribute will not submit that form element:

```
<form method="get" action="./">
    <select name="city" id="City">
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <select name="country" id="Country">
        <option></option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $('select').each(function(){
            if($(this).val()==''){
                $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        })

    })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

ok fine, if have empty selectbox. Then just put atleast one  tag, like

```
<option value="0">No data available</option>
```

So you may get 0.

Comment: if i do this i will always send them to php script right?where is the benefit?i cant underestand

Answer (score 0):

You can disable them by setting the disabled attribute like this:

```
<select name="city" disabled="disabled">
    ...
</select>
```

This should prevent the browser from sending this field in it's POST request.

Comment: i cant disable all of them because some of them are age and between query will execute for them..2 select options(minage,maxage).. minage(field) between 2000 AND maxage(field)2020 for example

Comment: I'm having this trouble too, because even if they are disabled they form will still post.